How to stretch video to fill VideoView area in Android using libVLC
I'm developing an Android application where I'm using libVLC to play videos. However, I'm facing an issue with stretching the video to fill the VideoView area without black bars appearing on the sides of the screen in landscape mode. I want the video to occupy the entire screen area regardless of the device's screen size.
I have tried setting the layout_width and layout_height of the VLCVideoLayout to match_parent, but it doesn't seem to stretch the video properly currently im testing App in Android 14.
Here's my MainActivity code:
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts.GetContent;


import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import android.widget.MediaController;

import com.shashank.sony.fancytoastlib.FancyToast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LibVLC libVlc;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private VLCVideoLayout videoLayout;
    private static WeakReference<MainActivity> instance;
    private MediaController controller;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000; // Time interval for double press in milliseconds

    private static final long REMINDER_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000; // 1 minute interval
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable reminderRunnable;

    private TextView serialIdTextView;
    private Timer timer;



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed(); // Exit the app if pressed twice within the time interval
            deleteTempFile();
            finish(); // Finish the activity to close the app completely
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        // Display informational message using FancyToast
        FancyToast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.INFO, true).show();

        // Reset the flag after the specified time interval
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false, TIME_INTERVAL);
    }


    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new GetContent(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                    // Handle the result here
                    playVideo(uri);
                }
            }
    );

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initialize LottieAnimationView


        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.openfile);

        // Set animation
        lottieAnimationView.setAnimation("openfile.json"); // Replace with your animation JSON file
        lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();



        // Check permissions if the device is running Android 6.0 or higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkPermissions();
        } else {
            // Permissions are automatically granted on devices below Android 6.0
            // Proceed with your logic
        }


        // Initialize the instance variable with the current MainActivity instance
        instance = new WeakReference<>(this);

        libVlc = new LibVLC(this);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);
        videoLayout = findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);


        mediaPlayer.setEventListener(new MediaPlayer.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(MediaPlayer.Event event) {
                switch (event.type) {
                    case MediaPlayer.Event.Playing:
                        // Video playback started, hide the icon, title, and video layout
                        hideOpenButtonAndTitle();
                        videoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        serialIdTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Show serial ID TextView
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.Event.Stopped:
                    case MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached:
                    case MediaPlayer.Event.EncounteredError:
                        // Video playback stopped or encountered an error, show the icon, title, and video layout
                        showOpenButtonAndTitle();
                        videoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        deleteTempFile();
                        serialIdTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide serial ID TextView
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


        controller = new MediaController(this);
        controller.setMediaPlayer(playerInterface);
        controller.setAnchorView(videoLayout);

        // Set click listener to show the controller only when video is playing or paused
        videoLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null && (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || mediaPlayer.getPosition() > 0)) {
                    // Show the controller when video is playing or paused
                    controller.show(5000);
                }
            }
        });


        // Ensure that the controller is properly attached to the video layout
        mediaPlayer.attachViews(videoLayout, null, false, false);


        findViewById(R.id.openfile).setOnClickListener(
                v -> pickVideo()
        );

    }

my activity_main layout XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- LottieAnimationView for the animation -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/openfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="openfile.json"
            app:lottie_loop="true" />

        <!-- TextView for the title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
            android:text="@string/please_select_a_video_to_play"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- TextView for displaying serial ID -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serialIdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FA0000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>


Minifest Code:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dedseec">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DedSeec"
        android:forceDarkAllowed="true"
        tools:targetApi="32">

        <!-- Define FileProvider -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.dedseec.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="*"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ded" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity


    </application>

</manifest>

Everything is working fine except for full-screen mode. I've tried all possible methods and concepts, but none of them seem to work in my case.
I've attempted several methods to achieve full-screen mode for the video playback, but unfortunately, none of them yielded the desired result.
